# Equation $2x^3+6xy^2+3x^2+3y^2-y=0$ defines $y$ as a function of $x$ around the origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

Show that the equation $2x^3+6xy^2+3x^2+3y^2-y=0$ defines a function $y=f(x)$ in the neighbourhood of $(0,0)$. Determine $\dfrac{f(x)}{x}$ and $\dfrac{f(x)}{x^2}$ as $x\to0$. Any leads?

Comment: Use the implicit function theorem.

Comment: can you explain a little bit more? I am sort of stuck

Comment: Sure. At what point in your try are you stuck?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks eighter way. Should I remove this question now?

Comment: It would be better if you posted an answer yourself.